# Probation period, ended or not?

Tags: probation

My contract states that my probation period is 5 months and that my area manager will give me a letter informing me about the end of it.

5 months passed, I did not receive any extension of probation period letter, my performance is being praised by my manager, my manager told me he did not receive any letter from HR and appeared not to be aware of the procedure (if he needs to write it, for example).

Given that four of my colleagues already received their letters from their managers and a few of us have not yet, I want to ask this question: How should I proceed?

Comment: Is your manager and the area manager the same person?

Comment: Your contract seems quite clear on this issue. Not giving you this letter should not extend the probation period. However, you'll have to show your contract to an employment lawyer to be sure. It's easier and cheaper to contact HR and ask for the letter.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I proceed?

Talk to both HR and your manager. Ask them what the procedure is in your company. Ask your manager to follow the process.